# i want to Include Parentheses in Spring JPA Specification's WHERE Clause

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How do I write this query in my repository

**this is my sql query **

```
select user, email, mot_de_passe
from utilisater
where (user='....' or email='...') and mot_de_passe= '...'
```

**I tried to do it this way**

```
@Repository("UtilisateurRepo")
public interface UtilisateurRepo extends JpaRepository<Utilisateur,String> {
    Utilisateur findByUserOrEmailAndMdp(String user, String mail, String mdp);
}
```

**But got a different result as if I was writing:**

```
select user, email, mot_de_passe
from utilisater
where user='....' or email='...' and mot_de_passe= '...'
```

Comment: You don't, write the query yourself. The finder methods are only usable for the simple cases, if you want more complex stuff write the query yourself. Either JPQL query or a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

For maintainability I would write the following custom query:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM utilisater u WHERE (u.user='....' OR u.email='...') AND u.mot_de_passe= '...'")
```

The query is explicit and there will be no possible ambiguity for future maintainers. Since you are returning a single entity you need to guarantee some uniqueness among the three attributes in your where clause.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution without using it sql query for ex: findByUser, findByEmail....

Comment: If you really want to go down this path, try findByUserAndMdpOrEmailAndMdp().' A and (B or C)' can be represented as '(A and B) or (A and C)' and with operator precedence this can be rewritten to 'A and B or A and C'. You may have to alter your parameters to make this work which would make things a bit awkward.